# getting String response from OKhttp

Tags: android

I want to get string JSON response to the main activity after making the connection I know it is running in different thread so please help me how I can get it and then return it from this method;

```
public class MakeNetworkConnection {

    private String mBaseUrl;
    private String mApiKey;
    private String mContentType;
    private String mJsonResponce;

    public MakeNetworkConnection(String baseUrl, String apiKey, String contentType) {
        mBaseUrl = baseUrl;
        mApiKey = apiKey;
        mContentType = contentType;
    }
    public String startNetworkConnection() throws IOException {

        OkHttpClient client=new OkHttpClient();
        Request request=new Request.Builder().url("http://content.guardianapis.com/sections?api-key=1123456").build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    mJsonResponce=response.body().string();
                }
            }
        });

       return mJsonResponce; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is about understanding how **asynchronous** tasks work. When you are calling `client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback()`, it will run in the background thread (off the main thread) and control will pass to the next line which is `return mJsonResponce;` And thus, it will **always** return `null`.

What you should do is to pass a callback method which will be called when the response is successful. You can create an interface to return the result:

```
public interface NetworkCallback {
   void onSuccess(String response);
   void onFailure();
}
```

Pass an object of this interface while making the network request and call appropriate method when network request finishes.

One more thing you will have to take care is that `OkHttp` doesn't return the response on the main thread, so you will have to return the response on UI/main thread if you are going to update any UI. Something like this will work.

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
      if(response.isSuccessful()){
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                       @Override
                       public void run() {
                          //return response from here to update any UI
                          networkCallback.onSuccess(response.body().string());
                       }
               });
      }
}
```

Comment: Sorry i didn't quite get that, what i understand from you if im runing MakeNetworkConnection() method in the main activity and i want to update the ui i need to get it in the main thread, but here im using a different helper class which i want to use muti times

Comment: how i can i get the output from this method and then update the ui in the mainActivity

Comment: @EmadJaber, great. Sorry I was not available to answer yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using calls asynchronously, you could use it synchronously with `execute()`.

```
public String startNetworkConnection() throws IOException {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
                 .url("http://content.guardianapis.com/sections?api-key=1123456")
                 .build();
    return client.newCall(request)
                 .execute()
                 .body()
                 .string();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

after advice from Rohit Arya i did the following:

```
public class OkHttpUtil {


public interface OKHttpNetwork{
     void onSuccess(String body);
     void onFailure();
}

public void startConnection(String url, final OKHttpNetwork okHttpCallBack) throws IOException {
    OkHttpClient client=new OkHttpClient();
    Request request=new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            if (response.isSuccessful()){

                okHttpCallBack.onSuccess(response.body().string());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

in the MainActvity i did the following :

```
        OkHttpUtil okHttpUtil=new OkHttpUtil();
    try {
        okHttpUtil.startConnection("http://content.guardianapis.com/sections?api-key=8161f1e9-248b-4bde-be68-637dd91e92dd"
                , new OkHttpUtil.OKHttpNetwork() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String body) {
                        final String jsonResponse=body;
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                //show the response body
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,jsonResponse, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure() {
                    //do something
                    }
                });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Change this line

```
mJsonResponce=response.body().toString();
```

To

```
mJsonResponce=response.body().string();
```

Hope help you.